# Describe the bonding in a tribromide anion, what is its structure?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, molecular-structure, lewis-structure

I'm thinking it will be linear with a negative charge on the middle bromine. Someone told me it is trigonal bipyramidal geometry with 3 lone pairs around the central bromine and the two other bromines above and below making it linear. Is this correct? Also is it just covalent bonding in the molecule?

Comment: Try looking up the structure of the triiodide ion.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, tribromide ion has the generic formula $\ce{AX2E3}$ according to Lewis diagram. Where  $\ce{A}$ is the central atom, $\ce{X}$ an atom bonded to $\ce{A}$ and $\ce{E}$ a lone pair on $\ce{A}$.  Using Valence Shell Electron Pair Repulsion (VSEPR) theory,  the geometry  of this ion will be
 :
[image]

So, the molecular shape is linear, while the electron pair geometry is trigonal  bipyramid.
 And the bonds in the ion are covalent.

Comment: While VSEPR concludes on the correct geometry, the way it got there is just plain wrong.